# drf_spectacular.utils.PolymorphicProxySerializer.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-spectacular

I am using a PolymorphicProxySerializer provided by [drf_spectacular](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.PolymorphicProxySerializer) but I am getting a strange error when attempting to load the schema

usage

```
    @extend_schema(
        parameters=[NoteQueryParameters],
        responses=PolymorphicProxySerializer(
            component_name="NoteSerializer",
            serializers=[NoteSerializer, NoteSerializerWithJiraData],
            resource_type_field_name=None,
        ),
    )
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

serializers

```
class CleanedJiraDataSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    key = serializers.CharField(max_length=20, allow_null=True)

class BugSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    failures = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, required=False, allow_null=True)
    suite = serializers.CharField(max_length=100, required=False, allow_null=True)
    notes = serializers.CharField(max_length=1000, required=False, allow_null=True)
    tags = StringListField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_empty=True)
    testCaseNames = StringListField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_empty=True)
    testCaseIds = StringListField(required=False, allow_null=True, allow_empty=True)
    jira = CleanedJiraDataSerializer(required=False, allow_null=True)


class BugSerializerWithJiraData(BugSerializer):
    jira = serializers.DictField()

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bug = serializers.ListField(child=BugSerializer())

    class Meta:
        model = Notes
        fields = "__all__"


class NoteSerializerWithJiraData(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bug = serializers.ListField(child=BugSerializerWithJiraData())

    class Meta:
        model = Notes
        fields = "__all__"
```

Basically, if a boolean query parameter is added to the request, I will inject some dynamic data fetched from the jira api. I am trying to update the api docs to represent to two distinct possible schema

```
PolymorphicProxySerializer.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'context'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass many=True when you instantiate PolymorphicProxySerializer, since you're decorating a ListView.

```
@extend_schema(
    parameters=[NoteQueryParameters],
    responses=PolymorphicProxySerializer(
        component_name="NoteSerializer",
        serializers=[NoteSerializer, NoteSerializerWithJiraData],
        resource_type_field_name=None,
        many=True
    ),
)
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: seems so obvious now! thanks a lot